# Java. How to make progress bar in IDEA console?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want my test run with progress bar in the cycles, but my function only shows me the full bar when cycle is over...

```
static void testProgress(int all, int now)
    {
        float num = (float) (now/(all*0.1);
        int current = (int) (num/1);
        int rest = 10 - current;

        System.out.print("\r[");
        for(int a=1;a<=current;a++)
        {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        for(int b=1;b<=rest;b++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");

    }
```

Comment: And were supposed to know how "now" is incremented? Or when this method is called? Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with `float num = (float) (now/(all*0.1); int current = (int) (num/1);` It's screaming logic error.

Comment: i use this function in cycles, and "now" is step of cycle. And I'm using `float num = (float) (now/(all*0.1); int current = (int)` to get current position of progress bar by using the leight of cycle and i'ts current step.

Comment: So, why isn't current `int current = (int)(((float)(now * MAX_PIPE_CHAR)) / all);`? Pipe character is `|` in case you didn't know. The 0.1 seems very arbitrary.

Comment: I want my progress bar always be the same leight

Comment: Also, the `(int) (num/1)` is equivalent to `(int) num`. The variable `num` is treated a float, so the `/1` will only divide the float by 1 (same as dividing by 1.0f) and returns  float, (no floor division occurs). Look at my answer to see what I meant when saying `int current = (int)(((float)(now * MAX_PIPE_CHAR)) / all)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, there is no way to simply overwrite the old progress bar and output the new one, for IntelliJ console. On Windows command line (and I assume Unix system), you can print the progress bar with and overwrite as follows (using `System.out.print`, and `'\r'` as the you're doing). Also making a more readable version of your progress bar (allows you to widen, and shorten as you like by changing the value `MAX_PIPE_CHAR`:

```
public class Tester {
    static void testProgress(int all, int now) {
        final int MAX_PIPE_CHAR = 10;
        float num = now * MAX_PIPE_CHAR * 1.01f; // 1.01f to account for any round off
        int current = (int) (num / all);
        int rest = MAX_PIPE_CHAR - current;

        System.out.print("\r[");
        for (int a = 1; a <= current; a++) {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        for (int b = 1; b <= rest; b++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");

    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { // to test, taken from Aleksandar (slight modification)
            testProgress(100, i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From **command line**:

```
java Tester
```

You get the progress bar that overwrites itself (Tested on Windows).

Comment: You can make the `1.01f` to `1.001f`. The point is to account for round off error when dealing with multiplication /division over floats.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you write all your values in one line by calling only `System.out.print` method and overwrite existing console output string again and again.

Try to use something like this to go to the next line:

```
System.out.print("]");
System.out.println();//inserts new line
```

Or more concise version:

```
System.out.print("]\n");//\n inserts new line
```

Comment: it is the goal, to re-write the line! to make it look like real progress bar, but it only shows me the complete bar....

Comment: it means that your process ends very fast. I checked your code with the debugger - function prints correct data at every step but then it's overwritten

Comment: @DmitryFeniks IDK if IntelliJ console give you enough control to show a progress bar being **redrawn**. A Command line might, but things might get complicated.